# .NET Framework failed to load libSkiaSharp native dll

Tags: .net, frameworks, native, skiasharp

I am using a QuestPDF library in .NET Framework 4.6. It requires SkiaSharp. I have a package SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32 installed, but the runtime still fails to load a `libSkiaSharp` binary.

[image: exception message]

A package is located at a solution directory:
[image: package presence]

But for some reason it is not loaded into runtime. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that the project had a target runtime of net4.6.1, but the SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Win32 had minimum Framework runtime of net4.6.2, thus, the netstandard2.0 version was used. 
Not sure why it could not load a native binary from netstandard version, but the fact is - it couldn't. 
The solution was to bump the project target to net4.6.2 and reinstall QuestPDF, NuGet package, so it would change csproj's path to package location at `packages` folder to net4.6.2 version instead of netstandard2.0.